# How can provide AWS cognito as SAML 2.0 IDP for SSO?

Tags: single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0, aws-userpools

I have an AWS Cognito where thousand of users already registered, Now I have a scenario where I have to share my user with a 3rd-Party application, where 3parth application want to use my Cognito users for login using SAML 2.0 IDP.
Where Cognito user pool should work as IDP and 3party application should work as SP.

Is there any way to provide Cognito user as IDP to a 3rd-party?

Like, We can use Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, Okla, Auth0 etc... IDPs into Cognito(SP), but in my case is the opposite where I want to provide Cognito as IDP.

Comment: Cognito was never an idp. I doubt it changed recently.

Comment: Do you mean we can't provide AWS Cognito as IDP.?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Look closer .. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar solution for one of the requirements in my project and came across this article where Auth0 has been used as a middle layer for acting as a SAML IdP.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/auth0-saml-cognito-user-pool/

AWS cognito here acts as an identity provider and Auth0 helps in transforming the request into SAML.

This has solved my use-case. Hope this is the same thing you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, are you able to share your setup configured for this? I am trying to do the same, but facing some errors like (incorrect email and password). Will really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hey @houdinisparks I've followed exactly same steps which are given in that document and it has worked for me. You my want to install "SAML Chrome Panel". This is a chrome extension to debug SAML request and response.