How to Set Up Amazon Cognito as the Sole SAML Identity Provider (IdP) Without Third-Party Integration?
I'm currently working on setting up Amazon Cognito as the sole SAML Identity Provider (IdP) for my web and mobile applications. Most of the documentation and guides I've found, such as this AWS blog, focus on integrating Cognito with third-party IdPs like Microsoft Entra ID or ADFS.
However, my requirement is to use Amazon Cognito directly as the SAML IdP without involving any third-party IdPs. Specifically, I need guidance on:
Setting up Cognito user pools and configuring them as the SAML IdP.
Configuring the SAML settings (ACS URL, Entity ID, etc.) within Cognito.
Mapping attributes from Cognito to the application using SAML assertions.
Testing and validating that the SAML flow works without third-party IdPs.
I've already gone through the official documentation on using SAML with Amazon Cognito, but it seems to lean towards setups involving external IdPs.
Is there any specific documentation, example, or community guide that covers setting up Cognito purely as a SAML IdP? Any detailed steps, tips, or resources would be greatly appreciated.

In as much as I have read,  Amazon Cognito does not provide its own SAML identity provider and only works with third party IdPs
There is a workaround however using the answer in this post

Is there any way to use Amazon Cognito as an identity provider (IdP) directly, especially for SAML authentication? I understand that Cognito typically works with third-party IdPs, but I'm looking for a solution that allows Cognito to function as an IdP without relying on external providers. Are there any workarounds or configurations that could make this possible?

check answer for this post this the closer response to your use case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049739/how-can-provide-aws-cognito-as-saml-2-0-idp-for-sso

Amazon Cognito is not a SAML provider itself. Instead, it acts as a SAML consumer. Cognito can integrate with identity providers (IdPs) that support SAML, allowing it to authenticate users against external SAML-based IdPs, but Cognito is not designed to be a SAML provider to allow others to authenticate users against the AWS Cognito pool of users.  So there are no tips to make this work.  AWS would need to add features to make it so Cognito could be a SAML provider, and unless/until they do that you won't be able to make it into one.
Instead, if you are going against Cognito directly, you could use an authentication flow like the ones presented under User pool authentication flow, but those options are not SAML.
